# Properties of $\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } \left( -1 \right) ^{l}{m+l-1\choose l} \left( 2 \,{\frac {l}{m}}+1 \right) ^{1-\nu}$

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients, summation-method

The sums defined by:

$$
S(m,\nu):=\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } \left( -1 \right) ^{l}{m+l-1\choose l} \left( {\frac {2
\,l}{m}}+1 \right) ^{1-\nu}
$$
are divergent. However they can be Abel-regularised as

$$
s(m,\nu):=\lim _{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } \left( -1 \right) ^{l}
{m+l-1\choose l} \left( {\frac {2\,l}{m}}+1 \right) ^{1-\nu}{x}^{l}
$$

Numerical and graphical evidence [(see figure below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OafNj.png) suggest that for all integer $m\geq 1$ and $\forall\nu\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, we have the following properties:

$$s(m,\nu)\geq 0,$$
$$s(m,\nu)\geq s(m+1,\nu),$$ and
$$\lim_{\nu\rightarrow\infty}s(m,\nu)=1.$$

Apart from the obvious case, where $\nu=1$, I have absolutely no idea on how to prove this. Are these relations known or does anyone know how to prove it? Any reference or hints are welcome.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim regarding $\nu\to\infty$ holds trivially, since $S(m,\nu)$ is absolutely convergent if $\nu>m+1$, and then the limit can be taken termwise (decrease in absolute value w.r.t. $\nu$ $\implies$ DCT).

As for the rest, the following integral representation(s) of $s(m,\nu)$ may be useful.

If $\nu>1$ (or even $\Re\nu>1$) then, using $$\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-bt}\,dt=\Gamma(a)b^{-a}\qquad(\Re a,\Re b>0)\tag{1}$$ with $a=\nu-1$ and $b=1+2l/m$, and the binomial series $$\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{m+l-1}{l}z^l=(1-z)^{-m},\qquad(|z|<1)\tag{2}$$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
s(m,\nu)&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-x)^l\binom{m+l-1}{l}\left(1+\frac{2l}{m}\right)^{1-\nu}
\\\color{gray}{(1)}\quad&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-x)^l\binom{m+l-1}{l}\frac1{\Gamma(\nu-1)}\int_0^\infty t^{\nu-2}e^{-(1+2l/m)t}\,dt
\\&=\frac1{\Gamma(\nu-1)}\lim_{x\to1^-}\int_0^\infty t^{\nu-2}e^{-t}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{m+l-1}{l}(-xe^{-2t/m})^l\,dt
\\\color{gray}{(2)}\quad&=\frac1{\Gamma(\nu-1)}\lim_{x\to1^-}\int_0^\infty t^{\nu-2}e^{-t}(1+xe^{-2t/m})^{-m}\,dt
\\&=\frac1{\Gamma(\nu-1)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\nu-2}\,dt}{(e^{t/m}+e^{-t/m})^m}.
\end{align*}

I would try this approach to show the decrease of $m\mapsto s(m,\nu)$. [Looks pretty good, and allows an easy asymptotic analysis of $m\to\infty$ by the way.] Also, integration by parts gives $$s(m,\nu)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu)}\int_0^\infty t^{\nu-1}\frac{e^{t/m}-e^{-t/m}}{(e^{t/m}+e^{-t/m})^{m+1}}\,dt,$$ applicable for $\nu>0$ (or $\Re\nu>0$).

Comment: Dear metamorphy, thank you very much, your expression for $s(m,\nu)$ appears to be correct when checking numerically. However, you write "it is easy to obtain", but I do not see how you arrive at that expression. Please forgive me to ask for an elaboration, but I'm just a beginner. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Yeti: see the edit.

Comment: Great answer! You beat me twice by a few minutes. I used the same approach when dealing with a very similar problem related to Clausen functions, which is why I would like to ask the OP, where the problem stems from?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I came across this problem while playing around with Chebyshev polynomials and just was curious if this was known stuff.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how this could help you. In any manner, it is not a proof.*

If $\nu$ is a positive integer
$$T_{m,\nu}=\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } (-1)^l\,{m+l-1\choose l} \,\left( {\frac {2l}{m}}+1 \right) ^{1-\nu}$$ is an hypergeometric function
$$T_{m,2}=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{m}{2},m;\frac{m+2}{2};-1\right)$$
$$T_{m,3}=\, _3F_2\left(\frac{m}{2},\frac{m}{2},m;\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m+2}{2};-1\right)$$
$$T_{m,4}=\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{m}{2},\frac{m}{2},\frac{m}{2},m;\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m+2}{2},
   \frac{m+2}{2};-1\right)$$ and you can see the general pattern.

The fact that $T_{m,\nu} >0 ~~\forall m,n$ is clear from definition.

Beside what you found
$$T_{m,\nu}-T_{m+1,\nu} >0 $$ there is also
$$T_{m,\nu+1}-T_{m,\nu} >0 $$ For example, using $\nu=2$ and various values of $m$, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m & T_3-T_2 & \text{numerical value} \\
 1 & C-\frac{\pi }{4} & 0.130567 \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\log (4)}{2} & 0.193147 \\
 3 & -\frac{9}{16}+\frac{9 C}{8}-\frac{3 \pi }{32} & 0.173437 \\
 4 & -\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\log (4)}{3} & 0.128765 \\
 5 & -\frac{275}{768}+\frac{75 C}{128}-\frac{15 \pi }{512} & 0.086587 \\
 6 & -\frac{49}{320}+\frac{3 \log (4)}{20} & 0.054819
\end{array}
\right)$$ This has been checked for a few values of $\nu$.

Now, using $m=10$ and increasing $\nu$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \nu & \text{numerical value} \\
 20 & 0.757273699599990 \\
 30 & 0.952389215988479 \\
 40 & 0.991943127308829 \\
 50 & 0.998685163156552 \\
 60 & 0.999787167124773 \\
 70 & 0.999965609645380 \\
 80 & 0.999994445189100 \\
 90 & 0.999999102847086 \\
 100 & 0.999999855104106
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Working with fixed values of $m$, the only explicit expressions I have been able to get are
$$T_{1,\nu}=2^{2-2 \nu } \left(\zeta \left(\nu -1,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(\nu-1,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$T_{2,\nu}=2^{-\nu } \left(2^{\nu }-8\right) \zeta (\nu -2)$$